# Prevent fixed element from overlapping scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I have a site where I'm trying to add a "contact us" tab in the lower right corner. [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Rothrock42/mx1vxed2/) of my mock up. The pink contact tab is over the scrollbar. I would like it to be just to the left side of the scrollbar.

I'm using `position:fixed` to put the tab in the lower right, but it overlaps the scroll bar. I could change the `right:0` to something else, but my understanding is that the width of scrollbars varies in different browsers, so I don't know which value to choose.

I've googled and found so many confusing and convoluted answers, yet none seem to actually address what I'm trying to solve.

How can I position an element to be fixed and not overlap the scrollbar.

Comment: Quite honestly, your page is all out of whack. If you Right Click > Inspect Element and hover over your body, you'll notice it has a height of **0**. This is never a good thing - just about every element of your page is out-of-flow. I'd assume your specific issue is because of the `position: absolute;` on your `#workspace`. Try removing it and going from there. See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mx1vxed2/10/).

Comment: I think your understanding is correct - every browser does scrollbars slightly differently, and on top of that you could have an extension changing the way the scrollbars look/behave and change your expectations for how that browser behaves. How strict is your requirement for it to be flush? Perhaps a simple design change is better than dealing with the nuances?

Comment: We already have some content on the left side and we can probably visually design around the issue. But I was just hoping there was an obvious, "Oh, you do this..." The issue is the text and all that stuff knows to reflow when there is a scrollbar. Why isn't there a way to position elements that also "know" about the scrollbar.

Comment: By default, elements do not interfere with the scrollbar; see [**this basic JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/8qhfgm3j/1/) in *any browser*. Your woes are not due to a missing positional attribute. As I said in my earlier comment, you've dug a hole for yourself and are asking why there's no easy way out. I'd suggest restructuring your page and CSS to make proper use of element positioning. You don't have a single element within the page-flow.

Answer (score 1):

While I have mentioned in the comments above that I'd suggest re-thinking your page structure, I believe the "quick fix" you're after is:

**1.** Remove `position: absolute;` from `#workspace`

**2.** Change `top: 30px;` to `margin-top: 30px;` on `#workspace`

**3.** Give your `#content-header` a `z-index` higher than the rest (`2` for example)

```
#content-header {
  ...
  z-index: 2;
}

#workspace {
  //top: 30px;           -- REMOVE THIS
  //position: absolute;  -- REMOVE THIS
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mx1vxed2/12/)

Comment: The structure of the main workspace and all is coming from our SharePoint and we can't rework that. You're right that if it was completely mine to control that would not be the way it was.I was just hoping that there was some obvious solution or property that I was missing which could help in this situation. The words in that container know how to wrap and not go under (or  over the scrollbar) so I was just hoping there was something that would let me also position the tab.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the scrollbar underneath the tab, you can use:

```
 z-index : 'number value';
```

Here's an updated version of your fiddle : [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mwq5Lqt9/)

Is that what you were looking for? Or are you trying to move the element completely away from the scroll bar so it would be floating of the side of the page? Or responsive to the scrollbar 'coming alive'? It would be easier to do a design change to the left side rather than deal with the nuances of the dynamic sizes of the scroll bar as @chazsolo mentioned.

Comment: I don't think you forked your fiddle, as its the same as OP's. I also think the z-index is not a true solution, as it sounds more like OP wants it to be flush against the left of the scrollbar.

Comment: No I forked, the link works for me the only difference is the z-index on line 58 I didn't change much. But you are correct it wouldn't work in that sense. I'll do some more digging if that's what OP wants.

Comment: You're correct, I had mistaken the link to be the same one. Sorry!

Comment: No worries honest mistake

Comment: Santi is correct. I don't want the tab under or over the scrollbar. I want it next to the scroll bar. But since scrollbars can have different widths in different browsers a set 15, 17, or 20 px won't do. Thanks for the ideas.

Comment: No worries. I'm actually working with a similar issue with a div on the right side. I'll let you know when I develop a solution. Hope you're able to figure it out

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the scrollbar using:

```
    ::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
    }
```

That way people can still scroll, but that's still not very user-friendly and only works on webkit browsers. I think what you're going for is a bit of a losing battle; I would put it flush against the bottom and give it the same right margin as the rest of the content on the site, then you don't have to mess with it and it would still look good.

Browsers like Safari completely hide the scroll bar unless you're actively scrolling, so unless you want to adjust it for every browser...yea no thanks :)

Comment: carl you've said something there "...give it the same right margin as the rest of the content..." I haven't given the rest of the content any special kind of margin. If there is a scrollbar the rest of the content moves over. If there isn't it moves the other way. I'm looking for a way to position content that knows it as well!

Comment: I was referring more to any actual content like text or images, that usually have some breathing room to the right and left of a document/layout. Fixed positioning is just a huge pain any time you get into the nitty gritty details like this. It's just not aware of anything around it besides the viewport. You could spend a lot of time on tweaking it a few pixels based on browser detection, but I can't think of any other approach, and that approach is bound to have issues once the next browser decides to change the appearance of their scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use below code

```
/* You just need to change this css and you'll get desired output - start*/
#workspace {
  overflow-y: overlay;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#workspace::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f500;
}

#workspace::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
#workspace::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
/*---------End--------------------------*/
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  line-height: 1.7;
}

#content-header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 30px;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  padding: .25em 1em;
}
/* You just need to change this css and you'll get desired output - start*/
#workspace {
  overflow-y: overlay;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
#workspace::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: #f5f5f500;
}

#workspace::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #bbbbbb;
}
#workspace::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}
/*---------End--------------------------*/

#body-container {
  min-height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  padding: 2rem 2rem 130px 2rem;
}

#footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: .8rem;
}

#floaty-tab {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 40px;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f;
  color: white;
  font-size: .8rem;
  padding: 1rem .5em;
}
```

```html
<div id="content-header">
  Site name
</div>
<div id="workspace">
  <div id="body-container">

    <div id="floaty-tab">
      Contact
    </div>

    <div class="anyipsum-output">
      <div class="body">
        <div class="anyipsum-output">
          <p>Bacon ipsum dolor amet drumstick shoulder pork loin jowl. Cupim pork chop shoulder hamburger ball tip. Pork ground round pork belly, venison short loin jerky boudin kevin capicola pancetta sausage corned beef shankle chuck. Landjaeger shank
            chuck leberkas bacon bresaola.</p>
          <p>Tongue meatball frankfurter shankle prosciutto shoulder fatback meatloaf turducken kevin salami drumstick bacon. Swine pork chop ham andouille leberkas hamburger venison. Kevin porchetta rump t-bone short ribs. Pork belly landjaeger meatloaf
            brisket, flank kevin turkey burgdoggen cow bacon ground round short ribs. Filet mignon salami capicola, cupim swine leberkas drumstick picanha. Bacon chuck pancetta pork sausage.</p>
          <p>Capicola beef ribs short loin landjaeger chuck ham cupim pork loin hamburger short ribs burgdoggen pastrami doner. Spare ribs pork belly sirloin kevin cow jowl. Tri-tip jowl pork landjaeger fatback ham bresaola brisket ground round boudin pastrami.
            Fatback salami meatloaf shoulder. Pork porchetta cow pork belly jerky swine leberkas shoulder burgdoggen tail pancetta pastrami spare ribs picanha chicken. Beef capicola ribeye porchetta flank kevin ham hock rump burgdoggen. Meatloaf venison
            prosciutto tongue picanha rump bresaola capicola t-bone doner ham hock jowl tail shank fatback.</p>
          <p>Strip steak shoulder ham brisket, burgdoggen ham hock pancetta cow meatball rump. Sausage tail bresaola tenderloin, short loin prosciutto turkey pork chop. Rump cupim frankfurter spare ribs pork shankle beef ribs biltong turducken. Tri-tip sirloin
            beef bresaola pork belly. Shank beef brisket doner turducken picanha, bresaola jerky fatback cow spare ribs ribeye hamburger.</p>
          <p>Turkey ham hock capicola, sausage bacon shoulder hamburger pork loin. Beef venison shankle ham hock drumstick shank. Bresaola ham hock tail shank capicola strip steak fatback. Chuck pork chop leberkas beef, shoulder fatback strip steak jowl
            flank.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      <p>
        The footer content
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```